# Opencsv : Not able to use the CsvToBeanFilter with CsvToBeanBuilder and annoted bean object

Tags: opencsv

I am not able to use the CsvToBeanFilter with CsvToBeanBuilder and annoted bean object. It gives "Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The header row hasn't been read yet." error.

Here is my filter -

```
private class AssetTypeFilter implements CsvToBeanFilter {

    private final MappingStrategy strategy;

    public AssetTypeFilter(MappingStrategy strategy) {
        this.strategy = strategy;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean allowLine(String[] line) {
        final int index = this.strategy.getColumnIndex("MF056");
        final String value = line[index];
        final boolean result = "CRDT".equals(value);
        return result;
    }

}
```

Here is my bean -

```
@ToString
@Data
public class DsbISINCsv {

    @CsvBindByName(column = "ID", required = false)
    private String sourceId;

    @CsvBindByName(column = "MF056", required = false)
    private String assetClass;

    @CsvBindByName(column = "MF057", required = false)
    private String instrumentType;

    @CsvBindByName(column = "MF086", required = false)
    private String derivativeISIN;

    @CsvBindByName(column = "MF091", required = false)
    private String classificationType;
}
```

Here is the code to read CSV -

```
public void process(File msg) {
    final List<MyBean> data = new ArrayList<>();
        final HeaderColumnNameTranslateMappingStrategy<
            MyBean> strategy = new HeaderColumnNameTranslateMappingStrategy();
        final Map<String, String> columnMap = new HashMap();
        columnMap.put("MF056", "assetClass");
        strategy.setColumnMapping(columnMap);
        strategy.setType(MyBean.class);

        // Parse one row at a time
        final CsvToBean<MyBean> reader = new CsvToBeanBuilder(getReader(msg)).withType(MyBean.class)
            .withOrderedResults(false)
            .withFilter(new AssetTypeFilter(strategy))
            .build();

        reader.forEach(a -> processData(a));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay several things here.

First, non-related but it caught my eye, is that you don't need to use the HeaderColumnNameTranslateMappingStrategy because you are doing a @BindByName in your object.  Either get rid of the setMap or try the HeaderColumnNameMappingStrategy.

Now as far as the problem goes it starts with that you should be using the IterableCSVToBean instead of the CSVToBean as that is one that allows your do process one at a time.  That said I believe you have built your own version of opencsv as opencsv is built in Java 7 and thus does not support the .foreach method.  Try an old fashion iterator to ensure that everything is processed sequentially and immediately as your implementation is either bypassing the parse altogether or it is threaded and is trying to process the second bean before the first (which the first bean processed is the one that reads and sets the header information).